# Link to form filters reset in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

Tell me please how to show in back_end template a link to reset filters ?. I tried this `url_for("filter/reset");` but don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `?_reset=1` to the end of your filter url.

If you have the `extra_params_as_query_string` option turned on, its `url_for("your_filter_route", array('_reset' => 1))`.

If not, do `url_for("your_filter_route").'?_reset=1'`